# Ember.js: dealing with a large number of properties in a model

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a model with a large number of properties, about 20.

```
App.Foo = Ember.Object.extend({
  foo01: null,
  foo02: null,
  ...
  foo20: null
```

Because I need to differentiate between values of `null` and `""`, I also have all these properties:

```
  isFoo01Set: function() { return foo01 !== null; }.property('foo01'),
  isFoo02Set: function() { return foo02 !== null; }.property('foo02'),
  ...
  isFoo20Set: function() { return foo01 !== null; }.property('foo20')
```

Please mind that the actual names in my real-world case are not `foo01..20`, but meaningful names that are all different from one another.

Then I need to have a whole bunch of actions to set/unset all those properties.

In my router:

```
  setFoo01: function(router, instance) {
    router.get('myController').setFoo01(instance.context);
  },
  unsetFoo01: function(router, instance) {
    router.get('myController').unsetFoo01(instance.context);
  },
```

So on until `foo20`. And then in my controller:

```
  setFoo01: function(obj) {
    obj.set('foo01', '');
  },
  unsetFoo01: function(obj) {
    obj.set('foo01', null);
```

And so on until `foo20`.

**Obviously** I must be doing something wrong. But I found that because of `handlebars` limitations (by design), I can't do anything in a template.

I would like to have something like this:

```
{{# each property in obj}}
  <a {{action set obj property}}>Set {{property}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

but it doesn't look like this is possible.

So, please, can you tell me that there is a better way, and what it is?

Comment: Perhaps using Ember.keys() could be usefull for you http://emberjs.com/api/#method_keys

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give a vague idea...hope this helps

```
App.Foo = Ember.Object.create({
  name: "",
  presence: function(){
    return this.get('name')!==null;
  }.property('name'),
  setFoo: function(){
    this.set('name', "");
  },
  unsetFoo: function(){
    this.set('name', null);
  }
})

App.fooArray = []
for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){
  App.fooArray.pushObject(App.Foo.create({name:"foo"+i}));
}

{{#each element in App.fooArray}}
  <a {{action element.unsetFoo}} href="#">un-set {{element.name}}</a>
  <a {{action element.setFoo}} href="#">Set {{element.name}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: As I said: "Please mind that the actual names in my real-world case are not foo01..20, but meaningful names that are all different from one another."

So they are things like `first_name`, `last_name`, `age`, `ssn`, etc. Real property names, not something with a number fro 01 to 20.

Comment: okay, in that case have an array nameArray= ["first_name", "last_name", "age"...], then App.Foo.create({name: nameArray[i]}) ...got it ?

Comment: How does that help me with the actions to set/unset all those different properties?

Comment: It seems that I did not understand your question then, may be can u put up a fiddle ?

Comment: Here every object has a it's own set & unset methods which will be executed on their corresponding click actions...is it not what u wanted ? and context is bound to the element

Comment: Hi, ultimately I decided to scrap this approach, and try to get a whole form in a modal window; thanks for trying to help!